# Selenium webscraping loop stops working for some reason after successfully scraping a couple of times

Tags: python, selenium

So I have made a Loop to get the data from a site, it works fine the first couple of times but then doesn't extract the data (that it successfully extracted before) anymore for some reason.

My outputs are as follows everytime until it breaks:

```
['Observation date:2021-03-19 12:22', 'Reporting Date:2021-03-19 19:10', 'Name:Egger Josef', 'e-mail:j_egger351@gmx.at', 'Profile ID:15034']
['Place:Gosau/Zwieselalm', 'Region:Österreich — Oberösterreich — Nordalpen', 'Location:47.53838°N / 13.47819°E', 'Elevation:1607m', 'Incline:34°', 'Aspect:SE']

['Observation date:2021-03-19 12:22', 'Reporting Date:2021-03-19 19:10', 'Name:Egger Josef', 'e-mail:j_egger351@gmx.at', 'Profile ID:15034', 'Place:Gosau/Zwieselalm', 'Region:Österreich — Oberösterreich — Nordalpen', 'Location:47.53838°N / 13.47819°E', 'Elevation:1607m', 'Incline:34°', 'Aspect:SE']
```

It takes the data from Lawis.at
[image: Those are the Elements]

*There are 3 scenarios:*

1. It works
2. It gets only the first data
   point on the last run example ['Observation date: 2021-03-19 12:12']
3. It gets most of the data on the last run but misses the last
   couple of data sets like here, its missing "Incline" and "Aspect" although the data exists

.

```
['Observation date:2021-03-19 12:22', 'Reporting Date:2021-03-19 19:10', 'Name:Egger Josef', 'e-mail:j_egger351@gmx.at', 'Profile ID:15034']
['Place:Gosau/Zwieselalm', 'Region:Österreich — Oberösterreich — Nordalpen', 'Location:47.53838°N / 13.47819°E', 'Elevation:1607m']
['Observation date:2021-03-19 12:22', 'Reporting Date:2021-03-19 19:10', 'Name:Egger Josef', 'e-mail:j_egger351@gmx.at', 'Profile ID:15034', 'Place:Gosau/Zwieselalm', 'Region:Österreich — Oberösterreich — Nordalpen', 'Location:47.53838°N / 13.47819°E', 'Elevation:1607m']
```

The error in the end is either one of those since it doesn't get the data it needs. (Those should be irrelevant since it should be getting the data and therefore those error code shouldn't be coming up)

```
incline = list_total[9]
IndexError: list index out of range

new_lst1 = lst[1].split('\n')
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Here is a complete test code if you would like to run it:

```
    from logging import log
import string
from selenium import webdriver
import selenium
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from numpy.core.fromnumeric import var
from numpy.lib.utils import source
import pandas as pd
from pandas.core.indexing import check_bool_indexer
import os
import re



dir_list = os.listdir()
print(dir_list)

#Functions

def googlepopupaccept():
    if WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='L2AGLb']"))):
        #driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[contains(@src, 'consent.google.com')]"))
        WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='L2AGLb']"))).click()
        
#Chrome Options
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
# options.add_argument('headless')
# options.add_argument('window-size=1920x1080')
# options.add_argument("disable-gpu")
options.add_argument("--incognito")

#Search for input in Google accept cookies
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
googlepopupaccept()

#Open Lawis
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path= 'chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=options)
googlemaps = driver.get("https://www.lawis.at")
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//*[@title="Profiles"]'))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//*[@class="button_subnav active"]'))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="filter_set_two"]'))).click()
country_search = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@class="chosen-search-input default"]')))
country_search.click()
country_search.send_keys('Österreich' + Keys.ENTER)

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="region_chosen"]'))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@class="chosen-search-input default"]'))).send_keys('Oberösterreich' + Keys.ENTER)

#Button Submit Click and open list to see details
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="filter_down"]/form/div/div[2]/button'))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="searchText"]'))).click()





#Click on each List Item and store data
def get_lawis_data():
    #Variable subject to loop change +1
    url_lawis_list_item0 = '/html/body/div/main/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]'
    position = 56
    
    #Make list from string
    url_lawis_list_item_list = list(url_lawis_list_item0)
    print(url_lawis_list_item_list)

    #Changing variable for loop
    tobechanged_index = int(url_lawis_list_item_list[position])
    
    #Variable lists of all data entries
    lst_total_observation = []
    lst_total_reporting = []
    lst_total_name = []
    lst_total_email = []
    lst_total_profile = []
    lst_total_place = []
    lst_total_region = []
    lst_total_location = []
    lst_total_elevation = []
    lst_total_incline = []
    lst_total_aspect = []
    lst_total_latitude = []
    lst_total_longitude = []
   
    #for testing purposes change while True: to "while tobechanged_index < 3"
    while tobechanged_index < 16:

        print(tobechanged_index)
        
        #Click on column
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, url_lawis_list_item0))).click()
        #open info tab
        WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="tab_info"]'))).click()
        
        

        #Change item in list +1 
        changed_index = int(url_lawis_list_item_list[position]) +1
        url_lawis_list_item_list[position] = changed_index
        print(url_lawis_list_item_list)
        
        #make string out of list
        empty_string = ""
        for i in url_lawis_list_item_list:
            empty_string += str(i) + ""
            
        url_lawis_list_item0 = empty_string
        print(url_lawis_list_item0)
        
        tobechanged_index = changed_index
        WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="tab_info"]'))).click()
        
        #Make list out of elements
        lst = []
        for elem in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@class="accordion-content"]'):
            print(elem.text)
            lst.append(elem.text)
            while '' in lst:
                lst.remove('')
        new_lst0 = lst[0].split('\n')
        print(new_lst0)
        new_lst1 = lst[1].split('\n')
        print(new_lst1)
        new_lst0.extend(new_lst1)
        list_total = new_lst0
        print(list_total)
        
        #Click on column
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, url_lawis_list_item0))).click()
        #scroll down once
        driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.DOWN)
        
        #store every index of List as a Variable 
        observation_date = list_total[0]
        reporting_date = list_total[1]
        name = list_total[2]
        email = list_total[3]
        profile_id = list_total[4]
        place = list_total[5]
        region = list_total[6]
        location = list_total[7]
        elevation = list_total[8]
        incline = list_total[9]
        aspect = list_total[10]
        
        print(observation_date, reporting_date,
            name, email, profile_id, place, region,
            location, elevation, incline, aspect)
        
        #Filter out and clean Latitude and Longitutde
        long_lat = []
        long_lat = re.split('[:/]', location)
        print(long_lat)
        latitude = long_lat[1]
        longitude = long_lat[2]
        print(latitude, longitude)
        
        #Variable lists of all data entries 
        data_entry_observation = [observation_date]
        lst_total_observation.append(data_entry_observation)
        data_entry_reporting = [reporting_date]
        lst_total_reporting.append(data_entry_reporting)
        data_entry_name = [name]
        lst_total_name.append(data_entry_name)
        data_entry_email = [email]
        lst_total_email.append(data_entry_email)
        data_entry_profile_id = [profile_id]
        lst_total_profile.append(data_entry_profile_id) 
        data_entry_place = [place]
        lst_total_place.append(data_entry_place)
        data_entry_region = [region]
        lst_total_region.append(data_entry_region)
        data_entry_location = [location]
        lst_total_location.append(data_entry_location)
        data_entry_elevation = [elevation]
        lst_total_elevation.append(data_entry_elevation)
        data_entry_incline = [incline]
        lst_total_incline.append(data_entry_incline)
        data_entry_aspect = [aspect]
        lst_total_aspect.append(data_entry_aspect)
        data_entry_latitude = [latitude]
        lst_total_latitude.append(data_entry_latitude)
        data_entry_longitude = [longitude]
        lst_total_longitude.append(data_entry_longitude)
        
        
        
       
        
        
    #combined list of all data entries for dataframe 
    lst_total = [lst_total_observation, lst_total_reporting, lst_total_name, lst_total_email,
        lst_total_profile, lst_total_place, lst_total_region, lst_total_location,
        lst_total_elevation, lst_total_incline, lst_total_aspect, lst_total_latitude, lst_total_longitude]
        
        
    # Build Dataframe
    df0 = pd.DataFrame(lst_total).transpose()
    df0.columns = ['Observation Date', 'Reporting Date', 'Name', 'E-Mail', 'Profile-ID', 'Place', 'Region', 'Location', 'Elevation', 'Incline', 'Aspect', 'Latitude', 'Longitude']
    print(df0)
    
    # print(lst_total_observation, lst_total_reporting, lst_total_name, lst_total_email,
    #       lst_total_profile, lst_total_place, lst_total_region, lst_total_location,
    #       lst_total_elevation, lst_total_incline, lst_total_aspect, lst_total_latitude, lst_total_longitude)
 
  
get_lawis_data()
```

It just doesn't make any sense to me. Why does it work and then just doesn't when it's the same thing...

Comment: Read [tour] and [mcve] and edit your post accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by removing

```
lst = []
        for elem in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@class="accordion-content"]'):
            print(elem.text)
            lst.append(elem.text)
            while '' in lst:
                lst.remove('')
        new_lst0 = lst[0].split('\n')
        print(new_lst0)
        new_lst1 = lst[1].split('\n')
        print(new_lst1)
        new_lst0.extend(new_lst1)
        list_total = new_lst0
        print(list_total)
```

and adding a webdriver wait for each element:

```
 #Make list out of elements
            lst = []
            info_date = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="info_date"]'))).text
            lst.append(info_date)
            info_reporting_date = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="info_reporting_date"]'))).text
            lst.append(info_reporting_date)
            info_name = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="info_name"]'))).text
            lst.append(info_name)
            info_email = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="info_email"]'))).text
            lst.append(info_email)
            info_id = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="info_id"]'))).text 
            lst.append(info_id)
            info_location = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="info_location"]'))).text
            lst.append(info_location)
            info_country = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="info_country"]'))).text
            lst.append(info_country)
            info_region = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="info_region"]'))).text
            lst.append(info_region)
            info_subregion = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="info_subregion"]'))).text
            lst.append(info_subregion)
            info_latitude = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="info_latitude"]'))).text
            lst.append(info_latitude)
            info_longitude = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="info_longitude"]'))).text 
            lst.append(info_longitude)
            info_elevation = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="info_seehoehe"]'))).text 
            lst.append(info_elevation)
            info_incline = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="info_incline"]'))).text 
            lst.append(info_incline)
            info_aspect = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="info_aspect"]'))).text 
            lst.append(info_aspect)
```